# WPF Caliburn Micro: Exchanging UserControls in a Window dynamically using ContentControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls, caliburn.micro, contentcontrol

This question is related to [Add a usercontrol to caliburm micro dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971253/add-a-usercontrol-to-caliburm-micro-dynamically). 
I have read any other related threads before open this new thread, but I still don't understand and find no solution. Please accept my apology if some of you take this as duplicate.

I have a window (MainView) contains "main" Grid (aka LayoutRoot) with 2 columns.

On left column there are 2 buttons: "Display View 1" and "Display View 2".

- If user click "Display View 1", the "Display1View" (is a UserControl contains TextBlock with Text "View 1") should be shown on the right column, replace the current one.
- If user click "Display View 2", the "Display2View" (is a UserControl contains TextBlock with Text "View 2") should be shown on the right column, replace the current one.

My sample code contains following views and viewmodels:

- MainView.xaml and MainViewModel.cs
- Display1View.xaml and Display1ViewModel.cs
- Display2View.xaml and Display2ViewModel.cs

In my sample code the ContentControl doesn't recognize the UserControl. What am I doing wrong? How to bind ContentControl correctly? Please feel free to modify my sample code. Thank you in advance

MainView.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TestCaliMiContentControl.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Main View"
    Width="525"
    Height="350">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="LeftNavPanel" Grid.Column="0">
            <Button x:Name="Display1" Content="Display View 1" />
            <Button x:Name="Display2" Content="Display View 2" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ContentControl x:Name="MainGridContent" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
public class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private ContentControl _mainGridContent;
    public ContentControl MainGridContent
    {
        get { return _mainGridContent; }
        set
        {
            _mainGridContent = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MainGridContent);
        }
    }

    public void Display1()
    {
        //MainGridContent = new Display1ViewModel(); // cannot convert source type error
    }

    public void Display2()
    {
        // MainGridContent = new Display2ViewModel(); // cannot convert source type error          
    }
}
```

Display1View.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestCaliMiContentControl.Display1View"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="72" 
                   Text="View 1"/>
     </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Display1ViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace TestCaliMiContentControl
{
    public class Display1ViewModel : PropertyChangedBase {}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I would start by recommending you read the Caliburn.Micro documentation, specifically the part about Screens, Conductors, and Composition: http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition

That being said, we can modify your code to get it working.

1) Since your `MainViewModel` is supposed to be conducting other items, it should descend from `Conductor<T>`. In this case, we will have it conduct the Caliburn `Screen` class.

```
public class MainViewModel : Conductor<Screen>
```

2) In MVVM, you view models should know nothing of your view. You should not see UI classes such as `ContentControl`. We could change your property to be of type `Screen`, but we actually don't need that property at all since we are using a conductor. So, remove the `MainGridContent` property and backing field.

3) Within your `Display1` and `Display2` methods, invoke Caliburn's conductor method `ActivateItem` to show the appropriate item.

```
public void Display1()
{
    ActivateItem(new Display1ViewModel());
}
```

4) In your `MainView.xaml` you will need to bind your `ContentControl` to the conductor's active item property, which is, by convention, `ActiveItem`.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem" Grid.Column="1" />
```

5) Finally, since your conductor is conducting `Screen`s, you need to make them screens. Screens are helpful because they have lifecycle and allow you to know when they are activated/deactivated. Do this for both Display1 and Display2.

```
public class Display1ViewModel : Screen {}
```

This should get you up and running.

Comment: thanks. As far as I can take from documentation, if I use Screen as base class of a viewmodel, I don't need to use PropertyChangedBase since it is already included in Screen. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, Screen descends from PropertyChangedBase. My rule of thumb is if I need to know when something is being activated/deactivated or I am conducting it, then I use a Screen. If it is just a basic ViewModel that makes up a small piece of the application, I'll just go with PropertyChangedBase.

Comment: In my MainView.xaml I can't have more than one ContentControl with ActiveItem, eg. if I also want to make the "LeftNavPanel" as ContentControl (so I will have LefNavPanelView.xaml and LeftNavPanelViewModel.cs). Any other design you may suggest? Thx in advance.

Comment: I tried to make nested like following. MainViewModel (is a Conductor<Screen>) has property LeftNavPanel() to activate LeftNavPanelViewModel. This property is called from MainViewModel constructor, so on start it will show LeftNavPanel. The LeftNavPanel (is also a Conductor<Screen>) has properties Display1() and Display2(). Well, it doesn't work since MainViewModel expects LeftNavPanelViewModel is a screen and not Conductor<Screen> :-(